# How to close dynamic added fields at one shot in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUDLH/8/

Here is the code.

```
<table id="table"></table>
<input type="button" id="addRowBtn" style="border-style: none;  cursor: pointer; 
                                                            background: #FFFFFF; color:  #023a6d;" value="Add Search Field">

<input style="display: none; margin-right: 552px; margin-left: 10px; float:  left;background:#00c800; border: 1px solid #00c800; color:#FFF; font-size: 14px;" type="button" id="delall" value="Clear">


$(document).ready(function () { 
$(function(){

var tbl = $("#table");

$("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
   if($("tr.tre").length<5)
       $("<tr class='tre'><td><select ><option>AND</option><option>OR</option> <option>NOT</option></select></td><td><input type='text' /></<td><td>&nbsp;in&nbsp;</td><td><select><option>title</option><option>All Fields</option><option>Authors</option></select></td><td><a class='delRowBtn'><input type='button' value='delete'></a></td></tr>").appendTo(tbl);  
    if($("tr.tre").length>2){
        $('#delall').show();
    } 


});


 $('#delall').click(function(){
      $(".tre").remove(); 
      $('#delall').hide();
   });

$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();        
  }); 

 });
 });
```

When I click on **add search**, field rows will be added dynamically up to 5 rows (limited).
Clear button will appear when the row count is more than two.

Now when I try to delete the rows one by one, they're getting deleted. The problem is when I try to delete the rows one by one till last. Ihe clear button should hide automatically, but it is not.

Please help.

Comment: Toggle the button passing the visible > what you want as minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your delete button event like this-

```
$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();  

        //hide clear button        
        if($("tr.tre").length<3){
            $('#delall').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        if($("tr.tre").length<3){
            $('#delall').hide();
        }
    });
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUDLH/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if condition

```
$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){

    $(this).closest("tr").remove();        
    if($('#table tr').length == 0){ // your table rows if 0 then clear button disabled
     $('#delall').hide();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this

```
$('#delall').toggle($("tr.tre").length>2)
```